# Insert multiple data, which have select statement and the FROM table of that select statement is same as the table I am trying to insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to insert data into MySQL table, which has select statement in it, and the table name of the select statement is same as the table name I am trying to insert.

If I want to write the statement in one sentence. The statement should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (data) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1
```

But how if I want to insert more? (In one sentence)

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (data) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1, 200, 300, ...
```

But failed...

Is there any way to insert multiple data, which have select statement in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `UNION ALL`

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (data) 
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 200
UNION ALL
SELECT 300
....
```